# Premanent freezes on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Someone created a new Eclipse master for the whole team. However, on my computer, Eclipse refuses to work properly. Indeed, just after the startup, and once I've added some "basic" projects, a right-click on the Package Explorer freezes Eclipse for *several* minutes.

Unfortunately, the `.log` file in my workspace directory is not of a great help as no error can be found in here.

What can I try to achieve to make my Eclipse working correctly?

I am currently running **Eclipse Galileo 3.5.2 Web** (build M20100211-1343)

Some installed plugins: `JBoss Tools`, `m2eclipse`, `Spring IDE`, `Checkstyle`, `JRebel`, `JSEclipse`, `MoreUnit`.

My `eclipse.ini` looks like:

```
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
384m
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.200.v20090519
-vm
../../Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_14/jre/bin/client/jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms128m
-Xmx384m
-Xss4m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
-XX:CompileThreshold=5
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling m2eclipse (just temporarily) and see if it get's better. If that's the case you should run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` for each of your projects.

I think it's the m2eclipse plugin that is slowing everything down.

Can you tell us if there are any eclipse process running while the IDE freezes, or are you unable to open the progress view?

Comment: You may be right, because when I disable "Build automatically", Eclipse is not freezing anymore. I will try to not use m2eclipse anymore on my projects, but it's weird that Eclipse is freezing just for that. For your information, when Eclipse freezes, no information is displayed in the progress view...

Comment: The freezing stopped at some point on my machine. I don't know if this was because i just let it work for a while and built every project i have or if it was for some other reason. But m2eclipse is usually a good reason for a coffee break. =)

Comment: Another idea: disable m2eclipse for the project that you don't need ATM or even close them.